# 2005 C4 Citroen starting problems

Tags: starting, fuel-system, citroen-c4

Hi I have just bought a 2005 C4 Citroen with a 4 cylinder petrol engine it has 104000 km on the clock. My issue is when the car is cold it takes around 10 tries to get it to idle properly. I have replaced all spark plugs and had them gapped at .035".

I have just taken it to a back yard mechanic and he showed me how to get it to start straight away. He took off the pipe in front of fuel body and poured petrol onto the flap. The car started straight away but I can't do this every morning.

Can the fuel body be worn out? Does it need to be replaced or can it be cleaned up? Or, could it be other issues?

Comment: I would start by checking fuel pressure, and the fuel pressure regulator, while cranking.

Answer (score 1):

Fuel pump may be working bad, or maybe fuel filter is not sealed correctly so fuel returns back to deposit.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is the start of a good answer, but it could use more detail as to how OP could figure out if that is the problem. We prefer to troubleshoot the problem rather than use the 'shotgun' approach here, which is to keep buying and replacing parts until the problem goes away. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

Check your fuel pump maybe it doesn't get enough electrisity to fire up the engine. Try to start you car with the gear in N and with full throttle. Thats the way how to start an old tractor (Steyr Puch). Last but not least check the battery, maybe it's old an weak.